# Servidor de producción aveces se pega al subir el WAR

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, glassfish, rendimiento

Tengo una aplicación en Java, usando glassfish y netbeans.

Resulta que cuando subo el WAR, el servidor se pega, hice unos cambios pequeños a la app, cambiarle nombre de label, mensajes en pantalla, etc.

Cosas muy simples, volví a subir el WAR y resulta que éste funciona perfectamente sin pegar el servidor, seguí haciendo cambios insignificantes a nivel visual, subí otro WAR y este ya se volvió a pegar, no sé la razón por la cual sucede esto, ya tengo así como un mes y aun no tengo solución clara.

Es la fecha y se sigue pegando, lo que hice por el momento es montar el WAR el cual no me dio problemas,

Los cambios que le hice a los siguientes son a nivel visual, cosas mínimas como cambiar las posiciones, el nombre, etc. No he hecho cambios a nivel de modelos ni configuraciones de nada.

NOTA: estoy usando JSF y Primefaces 3.5

Comment: Has intentado, en vez de subir el WAR, subir la carpeta!? el WAR_EXPLOTED? Saludos.

Comment: Yo trabajo en un fundación y tenemos que mandar los WAR a otra institución, ellos nos piden que les mandemos los WARS que acá en la fundación generamos, pero de todos los WAR que he mandado, solo uno no dio problemas, el resto pega el servidor.

Comment: WAR_EXPLOTED? no se que es.

Comment: Hay dos formas de hacer Deploy en glassfish, mediante un War (que es el archivo) o subiendo una carpeta con el out del proyecto. Puedes enviarles la carpeta?

Comment: No, no puedo enviarles la carpeta, tiene que ser el WAR :c

Comment: Lo extraño es que un WAR que les mandé funciono correctamente, el resto de WAR empezó a pegar el servidor y los cambios son mínimos, solo fueron a nivel de diseño.

Comment: Ok, has hecho deploy de tu war en tu ambiente de pruebas!? no tienes problemas? Si no los tienes, es muy probable que se trate del glassfish del lado del servidor en produccion

Comment: De hecho hay un servidor de prueba en el que desplegamos el WAR y funciona correctamente, pero el de prueba no hay mucha concurrencia y conexiones de usuario como en el de producción. Lo que nos dicen ellos es que nuestro WAR es el problema, no el servidor, ya que ellos tiene otros sistemas en el servidor de producción con las mismas tecnologías con el que fue desarrollado este sistema y funcionan sin ningún problemas y sin pegar el servidor.

Comment: Lo ideal es que, en ambientes de producción, se reinicie el application server (¡no el servidor completo!) al hacer un nuevo despliegue.

Comment: Si, de hecho tienen que estar reiniciando el application server diario, ya que el WAR esta pegando el servidor.